# Ant - How to define a multi processed build

Tags: linux, ant, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to find a way to define a multi processed (not a multi threaded) build on multicores with Ant on Ubuntu.
I guess  is not suitable

In the documentation: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html
I found the next "disclaimer":
"The primary use case for  is to run external programs ...
Accordingly, while this task has uses, it should be considered an advanced task which should be used in certain batch-processing or testing situations, rather **than an easy trick to speed up build times on a multiway CPU**.